# Equivalent of `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration` in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, configuration, configuration-files

I really like how `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration` works in `.NET` to manage and merge configuration. Now I'm starting a `Python` project and I would like to know if there's any package that gives comparable features there. What I especially like is the ability to add a series of `JSON` files that override one-another, and being able to specify some as optional.

On top of that, it gives the ability to override some values from environment variables using some environment variable name convention. That would be the cherry on top, but I can live without it.

Example: I have a default `JSON` config file (it would be called `appsettings.json` in `.NET`), and for deployments, I add another `JSON` file (would be called `appsettings.Deployment.json`). When the app starts, it looks for the first file (it's mandatory) and the second file (optionally) and combines the two by overriding values from the first file with values from the second file where it applies. The whole thing is deserialized to some object (I think I can easily handle that in `Python`).

If this is simply the wrong way of thinking about it in `Python` and there's some better way of doing mergeable configuration, I would also be glad to learn about that.

Comment: There is nothing equivalent to that in Python, which is simply a programming language.

Comment: I meant to find a package that does that similar to `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration`.

Comment: Indeed…that's what I thought you meant.